# Have "Operation Victory Arrow" or "Brave Witches" been released officially outside Japan?

Tags: strike-witches, brave-witches

Have *Strike Witches: Operation Victory Arrow* and/or *Brave Witches* (and its OVA) been released on Blu-ray or DVD with either English sub or dub?

I can only find *Strike Witches: Operation Victory Arrow* in Japanese exclusively while only finding *Brave Witches* DVD from Malaysia which I believe is technically a bootleg and of poor quality.

If not, has a release been scheduled for them?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the info for bd-dvd release for brave witches [here](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/daily-briefs/2016-11-14/all-brave-witches-bd-dvd-volumes-delayed-by-2-months/.108812).

Meanwhile , the operation victory arrow dvd's are only in japanese , although they may be in subbed format so you should check them out , there has been no official info on the dubbed release of dvd's.

Although crunchyroll seems to be streaming these series so you can check that out as well.

Comment: with the Brave Witches dvd the page says those are the japanese release. do they have english subtitles as asked in the question? (likewise with the Japanese DVD of Operation Victory Arrow). i ask because i generally don't think of releases in japan having English Subs

Comment: Yes what i thought of is the same that these are the japanese language release dvd's , so i looked into it a little and so mentioned crunchyroll streaming the anime ? should i remove the answer ?